# Como o ORDER BY sorteia as colunas em caso de um valor repetido?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query, order-by

Suponha que eu faça um `SELECT` mais ou menos assim:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "users" ORDER BY "createdAt";
```

Nesse contexto, se eu possuir dados que tenham um mesmo valor no campo `createdAt`, como o SQL ordenará esses campos?

P.S.: Eu sei que se tiver um outro campo na cláusula `ORDER BY` "resolvo" esse problema.

P.P.S.: Quero saber como o SQL reage a esse tipo de situação. Ele sempre mostrará a mesma ordem? Ou será meio que aleatório, caso haja esse tipo de "colisão" nos valores da cláusula de ordenação?

Comment: se não for possivel agrupar, o select retornar como normalmente retornaria sem o group, depende do banco, se a tabela tem indice, etc.. mas de uma maneira geral, é igual ao resultado do select sem group

Comment: O que vai acontecer grosso modo é que o item (i) não será maior que o (i+1) então i++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já que não usou um critério de desempate ele procurará a forma mais fácil possível para aquela *query*, o que pode até variar dependendo de uma série de critérios, ou seja, se quer uma ordem específica ou repetida então seja explícito em qual vai usar, não conte com uma ordem específica se você não especificar esta ordem. Não quer dizer que será aleatório, só não é claramente determinado.

Não há nada na especificação do SQL que determine isto, cada banco de dados pode fazer como quiser, e de fato pode mudar de versão para versão.

Answer (score 1):

O padrão `SQL` não garante que os dados recuperados tenham uma ordenação padrão. Sem um `ORDER BY` específico, a ordenação dos seus resultados será sempre **indeterminada**.

No `PostgreSQL`, a ordem das colunas que não fazem parte da cláusula `ORDER BY` é determinada pela maneira como o [`planner/optimizer`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/planner-optimizer.html) decidiu criar o conjunto de resultados.

Consultas simples como `SELECT * FROM tabela` provavelmente serão retornadas na mesma ordem em que foram armazenadas no disco, e podem estar ordenadas pela chave primária, pela ordem em que foram inseridas ou em uma outra ordem aleatória qualquer.

A regra é: **NUNCA** confie na ordem *padrão*, ela pode mudar da noite para o dia! Use **sempre** a cláusula `ORDER BY` se a ordenação dos dados é importante pra você.

**Referências:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/why-is-ssms-inserting-new-rows-at-the-top-of-a-table-not-the-bottom/5775

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by